# Read and processing data in spark output is not deliminated correctly

Tags: scala, apache-spark

So my stored output looks like this, it is one column with

```
\N|\N|\N|8931|\N|1
```

Where `|` is suppose to be the deliminated column. So it should have 6 columns, but it only has one.

My code to generate this is

```
val distData = sc.textFile(inputFileAdl).repartition(partitions.toInt) 
val x = new UdfWrapper(inputTempProp, "local")
val wrapper = sc.broadcast(x)
distData.map({s => 
    wrapper.value.exec(s.toString) 
}).toDF().write.parquet(outFolder)
```

Nothing inside of the map can be changed.  `wrapper.value.exec(s.toString)` returns a deliminated string(This cannot be changed).  I want to write this deliminated string to a parquet file, but have it be correctly deliminated by a given deliminator.  How can I accomplish this?

So current output - One column which is a deliminated string

Exepcted out - Six columns from the single deliminated string

Comment: @Chandan expected output is a parquet file with 6 columns, instead of 1 column that is a deliminated string.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @Chandan the output of ` wrapper.value.exec(s.toString)`  is a single string value of example `\N|\N|\N|8931|\N|1` and I want this deliminated into 6 columns instead of just being stored to parquet as one value.

Comment: after map and before toDF add following code `.map(x => x.split("|")).map(x => (x(0),x(1),x(2),x(3),x(4),x(5)))`